# FILTER JSON DATA CLICKING ON THE BUTTON IN REACT-REACTJS

Tags: reactjs

Please need help.

I am trying to filter JSON data by category, when clicking on button.

```
<button onClick={()=> filterType("men's clothing")}</button>

<button onClick={()=> filterType("jewelery")}
```

The problem is that when I first click on any categories button, it works. But then It searches from filtered data , not from original one and returns zero of found items.

```
const filterType = (category) => {
    setData(
          data.filter((item)=> {
          console.log(data)
            return item.category ===  category;
        })
    );
};
```

```
const Fakestore = async () => {
    const ApiGet = fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
      });
  };

  

  useEffect(() => {
    Fakestore();
 
  }, []);
```

Please help me

I tryed a lot, but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to store data in 2 variables - one for all the data, and the second one - for filtered data only. So on API response, the data will be stored in a variable for raw data, and on button click, you will update another variable, for example, `filteredData`.